# Multiple domain names pointing on same name server

Tags: web-hosting, domain-name, nameservers

I have 2 domain names. Can I point both domains to the same name server without having any adverse effect. Please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Nameservers are there to provide DNS service to many domains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use Addon domain or parked domain.Any adverse effect is nothing.